# Efficent waiter in python3 (tkinter) for serial packet from arduino

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, arduino, serial-port

I have a linear potentiometer connected to my Arduino Mega at port A0.
The board is connected to my Ubuntu PC using the factory provided USB-cable.

On the arduino I have a program running which reads the analog pin and prints it to the serial connection with the command `Serial.println(analogRead(sensorPin))`.
On the other end there is a python3 program running a tkinter application which has to act according to the potentiometer.
Currently I am reading the serial connection with `serial.readline()`.

I was not able to find a efficient waiter for that solution, which is not a constant while loop, which drives my CPU to 100%.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: in normal program you could use `time.sleep()` in loop to use less CPU. In `tkinter` has `root.after(time, callback)` to run the same function with delay and you can use it to create loop which use less CPU.

Comment: Already know that, but is there a way for me to do it like tkinter reacts to a button press?

Comment: see main.py on [read-serial-port](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/read-serial-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above by furas this worked for me:

[read-serial-port](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/read-serial-port)
(See main.py)